# Tooltip Remains After Widget That Created It Is Disposed

Tags: flutter

In flutter tool tips can get stuck open after when the widget that created the tooltip is removed from the widget tree.   Wondering if there is a way to manually remove the tooltip when needed?

Minimal Example To Reproduce

```
class BadToolTip extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _BadToolTipState();
  }
}

class _BadToolTipState extends State<BadToolTip> {
  bool _isDeleted = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_isDeleted) {
      return SizedBox.shrink();
    } else {
      return IconButton(
          color: Colors.redAccent,
          onPressed: () => setState(() {
                _isDeleted = true;
                // Todo: remove toooltip from overlay here?
              }),
          tooltip: "This will not go away!",
          icon: Icon(Icons.delete));
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure this is a bug, submitted a [bug report](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/141048)